# list side effect: how to make sure list input in a function remain unchanged

Tags: python

Why is the supplied list getting altered even when I have done all the operations in m list variable sliced from supplied matrix list.

```
def matrixflip(matrix, d):
    m = matrix[:]
    lenghth = len(m)
    if d == 'h':
        for i in m:
            i.reverse()
        return m

    elif d == 'v':
        for i in range(lenghth//2):
            for j in range(len(m[0])):
                (m[i][j] , m[lenghth-1-i][j]) = (m[lenghth-1-i][j] , m[i][j])
        return m
    else : return m


myl = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
p = matrixflip(myl,'v')
print(p)
print (myl)
```

[[3, 4], [1, 2]]

[[3, 4], [1, 2]]

but I need to have an input matrix(myl) unchanged

Comment: A properly indented code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing doesn't do a **deep** copy. It only does a **shallow** copy.

So, when you slice a list of lists, you will get a copy of only your **outer** list, but that copy will refer to the **same inner** lists.

So, when you modify that inner list, the modification will be visible from your original outer list, as well as from the copy of that outer list created by the slice.

To perform a deep copy, `import copy`, and call `copy.deepcopy(my_list_name)`.

Comment: Thank you..
So what should be the solution to this?

Comment: @TusharSingh, see my updated answer.